# For the two sample t-test statistics T, how to find the order with respect to the difference E(T| welch-t approximation) - E(T| exact distribution)??

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, expected-value, approximation

For the two sample t-test with unequal variances:
$T=\frac{\bar{x}-\bar{y}}{s_x^2/n_1+s_y^2/n_2}$, 
we usually use welch approximation, thus $T\sim t(f)$, where
$f=\frac{(\frac{\sigma_x^2}{n_1}+\frac{\sigma_y^2}{n_2})^2}
{\frac{\sigma_x^4}{n_1^2(n_1-1)}+\frac{\sigma_x^4}{n_2^2(n_2-1)}}$ is the approximated degree freedom.

**I want to find the order of $\mathrm{E}(T| welch~approximation)-\mathrm{E}(T|exact~distribution)$**.

**I suppose the order is $O(1/n^2)$**, Anyone can give me a confirmation ?

Comment: Clearly the order is not $O(n^{-2}),$ for the simple reason that the distribution depends on both $n_1$ and $n_2$ and is most sensitive to the *smaller* of the two numbers.  Under the null hypothesis with Normally distributed responses, both expectations are exactly zero anyway.  Please, then, edit this post to articulate the specific set of assumptions you are making about the data.